# how to use html5 history.pushstate with angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-routing, browser-history, html5-history

I am writing some new feature for my web app. where i write some script, and load via some tag manager, so that when my script loads it will target some UI components and removes from the dom and inject it's dom elements.

now the component it deletes have some button, which when clicked changes the url and loads the component mapped to the url. Please Note that web app is in angular and under the hood it uses angular routing.

now the script which  i am writing is outside of the angular app, so when i have deleted the UI by querying dom and injected the new element, i have used html5 `history.pushstate` to change the url. url changes but the component associated with it never loads.

it seems like angular dose not listen to changes done in html5 history.

could anyone please tell me how to make this work.?

please note my script is outside the angular so don't have any access to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t.

`pushState` is a way of saying “I have used JS to modify the DOM in such a way that if you requested *this* URL from the server you would end up with the same page”.

It doesn’t *cause* DOM changes.

If you want to change the state of the Angular application then you need the Angular application to provide you with an API to manipulate it. Since you don’t have access to it, you can’t add one.